Keyboard not working with Google Chrome on Ubuntu 24
I updated the Ubuntu 24 repositories with the apt update and upgrade commands. Then I installed Stacer. As a result, the keyboard does not work when I try to enter a search in Google Chrome. It does work in the terminal, text editor, and Firefox. I tried to uninstall the Latin American Spanish that the system had, leaving English installed, and that did not work either. I reinstalled Spanish-Spain and had no luck either. I appreciate your help.


Try updating everything:  sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade  2. Try removing Stacer: sudo apt remover stacer.

